# p-summable sequences

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am new to functional analysis. So please don't mind if my questions are little bit obvious/doesn't make sense. Suppose we have a p-summable sequence $(a_n)$. We know by definition that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert a_n \rvert^p \lt \infty.$$ So, does it always hold that the $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0$. I know this is especially true in case of Fourier coefficients in Hilbert Spaces. I wanted to know if this is valid in general.

Comment: $p$ summable probably means $\sum_1^\infty |a_n|^{\color{red}{ \displaystyle p}} < \infty$, right? if so then yes the null series test from basic analysis works

Comment: @CalvinKhor Hey thanks for replying. Yes, that's what I meant. I corrected in the question. So do you mean my assertion on the limit holds?

Comment: Yes, it is very easy to prove that $\sum b_n < \infty $ implies $b_n\to 0$, try proving the contrapositive

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, it's kind of intuitive as well. I just wanted to confirm. Thanks a lot!